# How do I save matched parts of a regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to sort out all APIs in the following text file:

```
DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
...
DLL Name: msvcrt.dll
...
DLL Name: KERNEL32.dll
...
DLL Name: WSOCK32.DLL
```

I thought of something like

```
$infostring = lc($infostring);
while ($infostring =~ /dll name:/g)
{
 print "found dll\n";
}
```

the only problem is, how to get the actual dll names or at least the position of the found string?

Answer (score 9):

You need to extend your regex to capture the name of the DLL:

```
$infostring = lc($infostring);
while ($infostring =~ /dll name: (\S+\.dll)/g) {
  print "found dll: $1\n";
}
```

The `\S+\.dll` will match one or more non-whitespace characters followed by ".dll" and the parentheses will collect the text matched inside them and store it in the variable `$1`.  (If you had more than one set of parentheses, the second would go into `$2`, the third to `$3`, etc.)

**Edit:**  Looks like the input specification was changed by an edit to the question while I was writing my answer...  The above would be for a single input string containing all DLL names.  Under the new format, with each one on a separate line, you'd instead want to use:

```
while (my $infostring = <$input_filehandle>) {
  $infostring = lc($infostring);
  print "found dll: $1\n" if $infostring =~ /dll name: (\S+\.dll)/;
}
```

No need to mess with `/g` on the regex or looping over matches if there won't be multiple matches in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($infostring =~ /DLL Name: (.*)/g)
{
    print "found dll: $1\n";
}
```

Please read the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) manual page. You need to use a capturing group (denoted by the parenthesis) to capture the DLL's name. You can then reference the captures later by using `$1`, `$2`, ..., `$n`

Comment: Indeed. The regular expressions tutorial (perlretut) is good, too: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html