# How can I substitute the nth occurrence of a match in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

Following up from an earlier question on [extracting the n'th regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552615/how-can-i-extract-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-match-in-a-perl-regex), I now need to substitute the match, if found.

I thought that I could define the extraction subroutine and call it in the substitution with the `/e` modifier. I was obviously wrong (admittedly, I had an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub extract_quoted { # à la codaddict

        my ($string, $index) = @_;
        while($string =~ /'(.*?)'/g) {
                $index--;
                return $1 if(! $index);
        }
        return;
}

my $string = "'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'";

extract_quoted ( $string, 3 );
$string =~ s/&extract_quoted($string,2)/'Perl'/e;

print $string; # Prints 'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'
```

There are, of course, many other issues with this technique:

- What if there are identical matches at different positions?
- What if the match isn't found?

In light of this situation, I'm wondering in what ways this could be implemented.

Comment: Couldn't you match the expression `n-1` times and then do the substitution on the nth match?

Comment: @mmyers: You may be on to something here, but even if I made the substitution part of the subroutine, there's still the issue of aliasing matches at different indexes to contend with.

Comment: If there are several matches, you want to replace all of them?

Comment: @leonbloy: No, only the one specified by the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can do something as this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "'How can I','use' .... 'perl','to process this' 'line'";

my $cont =0;
sub replacen { # auxiliar function: replaces string if incremented counter equals $index
        my ($index,$original,$replacement) = @_;
        $cont++;
        return $cont == $index ? $replacement: $original;
}

#replace the $index n'th match (1-based counting) from $string by $rep
sub replace_quoted {
        my ($string, $index,$replacement) = @_;
        $cont = 0; # initialize match counter
        $string =~ s/'(.*?)'/replacen($index,$1,$replacement)/eg;
        return $string;
}

my $result = replace_quoted ( $string, 3 ,"PERL");
print "RESULT: $result\n";
```

A little ugly the "global" $cont variable, that could be polished, but you get the idea.

Update: a more compact version:

```
use strict;
my $string = "'How can I','use' .... 'perl','to process this' 'line'";

#replace the $index n'th match (1-based counting) from $string by $replacement
sub replace_quoted {
        my ($string, $index,$replacement) = @_;
        my $cont = 0; # initialize match counter
        $string =~ s/'(.*?)'/$cont++ == $index ? $replacement : $1/eg;
        return $string;
}

my $result = replace_quoted ( $string, 3 ,"PERL");
print "RESULT: $result\n";
```

Comment: Interesting... I'd just replace the `$ori` with `$original` and `$rep` with `$replacement` so that it's clearer for others.

Comment: This is not currently using 1-based counting, this is 0-based counting.  Initialize $cont to 1 or pre-increment $cont in the regex to get 1 based counting, as stated in the coded comment and implied by the question.

Comment: Yeah, that was the only difference between the solutions posted by mobrule and leonbloy. @leonbloy: make it `++$cont` .

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** leonbloy came up with this solution first. If your tempted to upvote it, upvote leonbloy's first.

Somewhat inspired by leonbloy's (earlier) answer:

```
$line = "'How can I','use' 'PERL' 'to process this';'line'";
$n = 3;
$replacement = "Perl";

print "Old line: $line\n";
$z = 0;
$line =~ s/'(.*?)'/++$z==$n ? "'$replacement'" : "'$1'"/ge;
print "New line: $line\n";
```

---

```
Old line: 'How can I','use' 'PERL' 'to process this';'line'
New line: 'How can I','use' 'Perl' 'to process this';'line'
```

Comment: oops, i added my modified version before seeing yours, I swear :-)
they are basically the same (i missed the quotes, though)

Comment: @leonbloy Great minds think alike. And coincidentally, so do ours!

Comment: +1 for having it correctly count, and for having it replace with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex isn't too much more complicated than what you have, you could follow a `split` with an edit and a `join`:

```
$line = "'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'";

$n = 3;
$new_text = "'Perl'";
@f = split /('.*?')/, $line;
# odd fields of @f contain regex matches
# even fields contain the text between matches
$f[2*$n-1] = $new_text;
$new_line = join '', @f;
```

Answer (score 0):

See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@-):

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 5;

my %src = (
    q{'I want to' 'extract the word' 'PERL','from this string'}
    => q{'I want to' 'extract the word' 'Perl','from this string'},
    q{'What about', 'getting','PERL','from','here','?'}
    => q{'What about', 'getting','Perl','from','here','?'},
    q{'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'}
    => q{'How can I','use' 'Perl','to process this' 'line'},
    q{Invalid} => q{Invalid},
    q{'Another invalid string'} => q{'Another invalid string'}
);

while ( my ($src, $target) = each %src ) {
    ok($target eq subst_n($src, 3, 'Perl'), $src)
}

sub subst_n {
    my ($src, $index, $replacement) = @_;
    return $src unless $index > 0;
    while ( $src =~ /'.*?'/g ) {
        -- $index or return join(q{'},
            substr($src, 0, $-[0]),
            $replacement,
            substr($src, $+[0])
        );
    }
    return $src;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> pw
1..5
ok 1 - 'Another invalid string'
ok 2 - 'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'
ok 3 - Invalid
ok 4 - 'What about', 'getting','PERL','from','here','?'
ok 5 - 'I want to' 'extract the word' 'PERL','from this string'
```

Of course, you need to decide what happens if an invalid `$index` is passed or if the required match is not found. I just return the original string in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Reworking an [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552615/how-can-i-extract-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-match-in-a-perl-regex/2554259#2554259), match *n*-1 times and then replace the next. Memoizing patterns spares poor Perl having to recompile the same patterns over and over.

```
my $_quoted = qr/'[^']+'/; # ' fix Stack Overflow highlighting
my %_cache;
sub replace_nth_quoted { 
  my($string,$index,$replace) = @_;
  my $pat = $_cache{$index} ||=
    qr/ ^
        (                    # $1
          (?:.*?$_quoted.*?) # match quoted substrings...
            {@{[$index-1]}}  # $index-1 times
        )
        $_quoted             # the ${index}th match
      /x;

  $string =~ s/$pat/$1$replace/;
  $string;
}
```

For example

```
my $string = "'How can I','use' 'PERL','to process this' 'line'";
print replace_nth_quoted($string, 3, "'Perl'"), "\n";
```

outputs

```
'How can I','use' 'Perl','to process this' 'line'
```