# How to solve this match and replace problem of only nth occurrence of a word in a file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a file which has these few lines

```
Hello abc
hii
how are you
Hello abc
```

If I want to replace the 2nd occurrence of abc by xyz, how can I do?

I want an output like

```
Hello abc
hii
how are you
Hello xyz
```

I tried doing `perl -pi -e 's/abc/xyz/ if $. == 2' filename`. It is not working for me. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Perhaps, something like `perl -0777 -pi -e 's/^.*?abc.*?\Kabc/xyz/s' filename` will do.

Comment: related: for replacing nth occurrence per line, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555662/how-can-i-substitute-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-match-in-a-perl-regex

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -i -pe's/abc/ ++$count == 2 ? "xyz" : "abc" /eg' file
```

This works even if `abc` appears more than once per line.

Comment: Thanks it is working. If I want to add this in a perl script, it is not working by putting this inside system command. I am trying to do like this system("perl -i -pe's/abc/ ++$count == 2 ? "xyz" : "abc" /eg' file")

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of time `abc` appears and subst if equal 2:

```
perl -i -pe'$found++ if /abc/; s/abc/xyz/ if $found ==2' filename
```

Comment: Assumes `abc` only appears once per line.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it as a script. The first argument is the pattern, the second the replacement, the third the number of repetitions and the forth the file, you can also omit the file and insert the data vía stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.28;
my $patt = shift;
my $rep = shift;
my $nth = shift;
my $reps = 0;
while (<>) {
    $reps++ if /$patt/;
    s/$patt/$rep/ if (/$patt/ && $reps == $nth);
    print $_;
}
```